# How can I place an Adsense ad (script tags) inside of javascript tags?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I put an Adsense ad inside of javascript tags?

```
<script type="text javascript">
var ad = "<script type="text/javascript"><!--
          google_ad_client = "ca-pub-12345";
          google_ad_slot = "12345";
          google_ad_width = 728;
          google_ad_height = 90;
          //-->
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript"
          src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
          </script>";
</script>
```

The above obviously doesn't work.  But, it demonstrates what I'm trying to do.  Can any figure out how to effectively do this?  Thanks.

**UPDATE**
This still gives me a syntax error

```
var ad = "<script type='text/javascript'><!--
                            google_ad_client = 'ca-pub-12345';
                            /* plastic surgery body large banner */
                            google_ad_slot = '12345';
                            google_ad_width = 728;
                            google_ad_height = 90;
                            //-->
                            </script>
                            <script type='text/javascript'
                            src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js'>
                            </script>";
```

Comment: actually it doesn't demonstrate much. Could you elaborate why you need to do this?

Comment: you just want to store it in the variable? Then either escape the quotes like this inside the string
var ad = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> or use apostrophes
"<script type='text/javascript'>

Comment: Also,you are trying to create nested scripts!

Comment: Check out the update.  That still gives me syntax errors.  Also, it's for conditional ads based on the hash in the URL.

Comment: You have to "hide" the `</script>` from the browser. Simplest way is `<\/script>`.

Comment: Right, it still has errors.  Can someone provide an answer with the ad properly escaped.  I "\" escaped the script tags & put all single quotes inside of double quotes, but am still getting a syntax error.

Comment: `var newScript = document.createElement('script');
  newScript.type='text/javascript';
  newScript.src= adContents;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);`

this is how you can you can create a new script and append it to the head.Of course,you have to write the code for adContents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first part is your publisher-identification information. That's just script, so either put it in directly:

```
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-12345";
google_ad_slot = "12345";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
```

... or you can use eval:

```
var ad = [
  'google_ad_client = "ca-pub-12345";',
  'google_ad_slot = "12345";',
  'google_ad_width = 728;',
  'google_ad_height = 90;' ].join('');
eval(ad);
```

`document.write()` can be used to create `<script>` tags, but beware: MSIE had a bug that scanned for the word `<script>` so always break it up in an expression:

```
<script>
document.write('<scr'+ 'ipt type="text/javascript" ');
document.write(' src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">');
document.write('</scri' + ' ipt>');
</script>
```

In fact, if you've already gotten everything into an `ad` variable, you can simply:

```
document.write(ad);
```

The only problem you might run into is the fact that you can't do this as the result of an Ajax call. If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax('//host/my/tag.js', {
  dataType: 'text',
  success: function(text) {
    $('#target-id').html(text);
  }
});
```

jQuery will automatically work out how to activate the script tags into those spots, however this may not work for certain kinds of rich media creative.

Comment: That's not a "bug" - the HTML parser has absolutely no choice but to blindly scan for a `</script>` closing tag, as it has no ability to actually parse the contents of a `<script>` block - which, it should be noted, may be absolutely anything and not necessarily JavaScript.